# Magento 2 GetCustomer Not Returning

Tags: magento2, orders, customer

I have the following Observer set up and can get the OrderID but not the customer name. Here is what I have:

```
namespace Veratad\AgeVerification\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class ProcessOrder implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            try {

                $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
                $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
                $fn = $order->getCustomerFirstname();
                $ln = $order->getCustomerLastname();


                $order->setVeratad($fn);
                $order->save();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                error_log($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not getting the complete data from your order object.
Try to load the complete data first.
Use following code to load your order and get all data.

```
namespace Veratad\AgeVerification\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProcessOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $order;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {

            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();

            $orderData = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($order_id);

            $fn = $orderData->getCustomerFirstname();
            $ln = $orderData->getCustomerLastname();

            $order->setVeratad($fn);
            $order->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and get the following error:

    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor could not be converted to string

at this line $orderData = $this->$order->loadByIncrementId($order_id);

Comment: This has solved the problem 

    $orderData = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($order_id);

                    $fn = $orderData->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();

Answer (score 1):

You are getting order Id But not Customer Name

So please try below code may be it can help:

```
$orderData->getCustomerFirstname() ?  $orderData->getCustomerName() :  $orderData->getBillingAddress()->getName())
```